# Why defining Flowable I could receive updates of the DB

Tags: android, persistence, rx-java

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM userdata")
 Flowable<List<UserData>> allUserDatas();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
List<Long> insert(List<UserData> datas);


userDao.allUserDatas()
take(1).
filter(....)
    .subscribeOn(io())
    .observeOn(mainThread())
    .subscribe(userDatas -> Log.i("TAG",""+userDatas));
```

I added fetching with subscription in the same fragment in onAttach() but after DB update it doesn't call the subscription of fetching from DB, why

Comment: Please post the Fragment code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was because of `take(1)`, as it makes complete and that is why I could not listen to changes. Removing `take(1)` fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have to add your Flowable allUserDatas() to an instance of CompositeDisposable and then your subscription will be alive until you call clear on CompositeDisposable.

Comment: no, it doesn't work ,when for the first I open the fragment it works ,but  then when I'm on that fragment and deleting or updating in DB it doesn't call